# How to identify the page has iframe in Selenium using Java Code?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium. The webpages, I have to automate, have iframes for some pages and not for the rest. How to identify whether there is iframe or not so as for that particular page in java only and not from the firebug. If the page has iframe use
                                                       `webdriver.switchTo().defaultContent();` else check for xpath directly

Comment: My post can be considered as discussion but anyway. I believe you do not need to make such workaround to search frame and switch into. What if you have two iframes or frame in frame? Which frame will be target? I think, if you use page object pattern and have classes where you describe needed web elements then you will get rid of many problems. Especially from creating such generic method to check whether iframe is present in page source and switch frames conditionally. code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects -- it requires some efforts to start but benefits outweigh drawbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the page in browser and see HTML code for the page using Firebug, Developer Tools etc. If HTML has tag `iframe`, that means your page has iframe and hence you'll have to use `driver.switchTo.frame(frame);` to interact with elements within the frame.

If you want to check with Java code, do following:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("iframe"); //this will return true if there is iframe
```

Comment: No I have to make it generic.How to check for the page loaded it has iframe or not from java code.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Can we check from java code from the xpath whether that element is present in iFrame?

Comment: YOu can check for element's presence in iframe only after switching to that iframe.

Comment: Ok.In one page there is iframe below the elements which i have to automate. driver.getPageSource().contains("iframe"); this is giving me true as page is having that iframe.but that elements are not present in iframe.

Comment: If your element isn't in frame, you can interact with it directly; however if element is in frame, then you first will have to switch to that frame `driver.switchTo.frame("frameid or framename here");`, only then you'll be able to interact with that element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52293/discussion-between-irunner-and-tdhm)

Comment: This fails if you have there is any word iframe within the HTML document. In my case I had a javascript import in HTML but there was no real existing iframe element.

Answer (score 3):

Try to find iframe(s) on page:

```
List<WebElement> iframes = webDriver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
```

There will all found iframes as list of WebElement.

If iframes.size() > 0 it means that iframes found on page. And vice versa.

So if iframes found you can work with them as with webelements. In example you can switch to any iframe from the list do something inside it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `By.tagName` method to find `iframes`

```
int count = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size() ;
if(count == 0){
   // No frames          
}else{
   // Frames present         
}
```